# Finding out number of bits that have changed (bitwise operator)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a bit string that is generated based on user input. I also have another bit string that I use to perform bitwise & with the generated bit string. What I would like to know is how to find out how many bits of the generated bit string has changed from the & operation. So let say if I have 10000101 as generated bit string and 00101111 as a second bit string I use for & operation. The output of the process should be 1 since only the first bit of the generate bit string has changed. How do I do that?

Comment: It should be easy to just loop over the bits of the generated bit-string and compare with the original, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to XOR the result with the original to identify which bits were changed:

```
changedBits = (userInput & generatedInput) ^ userInput
```

Then, you need to calculate the [Hamming Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/222364) of the `changedBits` value:

```
int hammingWeight(int i) {
     i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x55555555);
     i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x33333333);
     return (((i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >>> 24;
}

int numberOfChangedBits = hammingWeight(changedBits);
```

Adjust as needed depending on how many bits your inputs are.

Comment: Awesome! That's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @harold : Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is bitwise XOR (exclusively OR), or `a^b`:

```
   10000101 ^ 00101111 → 10101010
```

Is is logically equivalent to `(~a&b) | (a&~b)`